Boost Beast WebSocket server Opening and Closing connection does not deallocate all memory on heap
I have been working to understand a series of unexplained memory allocations that don’t make sense in the boost beast websocket framework. I have taken the example of the async server implementation from the boost page and modified it to fit my needs.
During testing, I have been using _CrtMemState an _CrtMemCheckpoint to read the size of the heap. For the server implementation, the socket is not closed from the server application. A single connection is made at a time. Multiple connections has not been introduced in testing. The websocket will only instantiate and destroy when the client performs a connection and close, respectively.
I have isolated to just the websocket code and run a series of heap measurements. From python, I am connecting to the test code and closing the connection after a couple of seconds. Wait minimum 2 second and repeat. A measurement is taken every 500 ms. I am watching the state of the heap after the session has been fully closed and destroyed. From the measurements, I have recorded the following:
Initial start:             25009  (Ready to accept connection requests)
After First Disconnection:    29752
After Second Disconnection:   30688
After Third Disconnection:    30873
The jump from Initial Start and First Disconnection, I believe is from static objects constructed. After that, every disconnection request should return back to First Disconnection value. The reported values after a successful disconnection are continually going upwards.
During start-up, the manager will instantiate the listener and run on the ioc.
run()
{
    auto const address = net::ip::make_address(SRV_ADDRESS.c_str());
    auto const threads = std::max(1, MAX_THREAD_COUNT);
    
    net::io_context ioc{ threads };

    std::make_shared<Listener>(ioc, net::ip::tcp::endpoint{ address, static_cast<unsigned short>(PORT) }, __namespace_router)->run();

    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    v.reserve(threads - 1);
    for (auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        v.emplace_back([&ioc] {ioc.run(); });
    }
    ioc.run();
}

void WebSocketManager::registerSession(std::shared_ptr<Session>& pSession)
{
    __namespace_router->getActiveSessions()->setValue(__namespace_router->getActiveSessions()->getValue<int>() + 1);
    __sessions.push_back(pSession);
}

void WebSocketManager::updateSessions()
{
    for (vector<std::shared_ptr<Session>>::iterator itr = __sessions.begin(); itr != __sessions.end();)
    {
        if (itr->get()->isRunning())
        {
            ++itr;
        }
        else
        {
            __namespace_router->removeSession(*itr);
            (*itr).reset();
            itr = __sessions.erase(itr);
            __namespace_router->getActiveSessions()->setValue(__namespace_router->getActiveSessions()->getValue<int>() - 1);
        }
    }
}

Below is my Listener class, as copied from Vinnie Falco's websocket_server_async.cpp (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp)
Listener::Listener(net::io_context& ioc, tcp::endpoint endpoint, std::shared_ptr<NamespaceRouter>& pSocketMessageRouter)
    :
    ioc_(ioc)
    , acceptor_(ioc)
    , __namespace_router(pSocketMessageRouter)
{
    beast::error_code ec;

    // Open the acceptor
    acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        socket_fail(ec, "open");
        return;
    }

    // Allow address reuse
    acceptor_.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        socket_fail(ec, "set_option");
        return;
    }

    // Bind to the server address
    acceptor_.bind(endpoint, ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        socket_fail(ec, "bind");
        return;
    }

    // Start listening for connections
    acceptor_.listen(
        net::socket_base::max_listen_connections, ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        socket_fail(ec, "listen");
        return;
    }
}

void Listener::run()
{
    do_accept();
}

void Listener::do_accept()
{
    // The new connection gets its own strand
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        net::make_strand(ioc_),
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &Listener::on_accept,
            shared_from_this()));
}

void Listener::on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        socket_fail(ec, "accept");
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Session create" << std::endl;
        // Create the session and run it
        std::shared_ptr<Session> session = std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket), __namespace_router);
        WebSocketManager::Instance()->registerSession(session);
        session->run();
    }

    // Accept another connection
    do_accept();
}

The session register will save the session in the manager and will destroy it when the session has been closed by the client. There is another thread that looks at the state of the session and destroy the pointer when not used.
I only copied the session instantiation, initial read, and destructor since I have not started testing the reading/writing of data after a successful connection.
Session::Session(tcp::socket&& socket, std::shared_ptr<NamespaceRouter>& pSocketMessageRouter)
    : ws_(std::move(socket))
    , __namespace_router(pSocketMessageRouter)
{
    expected = 0;
    actual = 0;
    __is_executing = true;
}

Session::~Session()
{
    std::cout << this << " Session Destroyed" << std::endl;
    boost::beast::websocket::close_reason cr(boost::beast::websocket::close_code::normal);
    boost::beast::error_code ec;
    buffer_in_.consume(buffer_in_.size() + 1);
    ws_.next_layer().socket().close();
    ws_.next_layer().cancel();
    ws_.next_layer().close();
    ws_.close(boost::beast::websocket::close_code::normal, ec);
    
    __is_executing = false;
    
    queue_.clear();
}

void Session::run()
{
    // We need to be executing within a strand to perform async operations
    // on the I/O objects in this session. Although not strictly necessary
    // for single-threaded contexts, this example code is written to be
    // thread-safe by default.

    net::dispatch(ws_.get_executor(),
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &Session::on_run,
            shared_from_this()));
}

void Session::on_run()
{
    // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
    ws_.set_option(
        websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
            beast::role_type::server));

    // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
    ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
        [](websocket::response_type& res)
        {
            res.set(http::field::server,
            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
            "websocket - server - async");
        }));
    ws_.read_message_max(64 * 1024 * 1024);
    ws_.write_buffer_bytes(16 * 1024 * 1024);

    // Accept the websocket handshake
    ws_.async_accept(
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &Session::on_accept,
            shared_from_this()));
}

void Session::on_accept(beast::error_code ec)
{
    if (ec)
        return socket_fail(ec, "accept");

    // Read a message
    ws_.async_read(
        buffer_in_,
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &Session::on_read,
            shared_from_this()));
}

void Session::on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t)
{
    // This indicates that the session was closed
    if (ec == websocket::error::closed) {
        ws_.next_layer().socket().close();
        ws_.next_layer().release_socket();
        return;
    }
    else if (ec == beast::error::timeout)
    {
        std::cout << "Read Request Failed" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (ec) {
        socket_fail(ec, "read");
    }

    // Sends the result of the buffer to the router to be routed accordingly
    __namespace_router->onChange(shared_from_this(), beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_in_.data()));
    buffer_in_.consume(buffer_in_.size());
    buffer_in_.clear();
    if (ws_.is_open())
    {
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_in_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &Session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }
}

When a successful connection has been completed, the on_accept method should execute which means I am waiting for either a read request from client or a write request from server. Upon client request to close the session the ec should be "closed" which means the session needs to be teared down and ultimately destroyed.
A lot of the code modification/experimentation to cancel/close the socket and drain the buffers have been taken from other examples and reading other stack overflow questions/solutions. From the data I am recording, I am unable to explain why there are allocated bytes on the heap when the session has been "fully" destroyed. I believe I have the buffer fully deconstructed and the socket fully closed and "drained". I have attempted to perform a drain in the destructor but get a 10009 error. This tells me the socket is fully closed and the buffers should be fully drained internally. Questions to the community:
What am I missing in the analysis of my code?
Am I misunderstanding the implementation of the websocket or buffers to close/drain them properly?
Self-contained code example:
//
// Copyright (c) 2017 Vinnie Falco (vinnie dot falco at gmail dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
// Official repository: https://github.com/boostorg/beast
//

//#include "../common/helpers.hpp"
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include <crtdbg.h>

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

static void socket_fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

class Session
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{
private:
    websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream> ws_;
    //beast::flat_buffer buffer_out_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_in_;

public:
    Session(tcp::socket&& socket)
        : ws_(std::move(socket))
    {

    }

    virtual ~Session()
    {
        std::cout << "Session Destroyed" << std::endl;
        boost::beast::error_code ec;
        buffer_in_.consume(buffer_in_.size() + 1);
        ws_.next_layer().cancel();
        ws_.next_layer().socket().lowest_layer().close();
        ws_.close(boost::beast::websocket::close_code::normal, ec);
    }

    void run()
    {
        // We need to be executing within a strand to perform async operations
        // on the I/O objects in this session. Although not strictly necessary
        // for single-threaded contexts, this example code is written to be
        // thread-safe by default.

        net::dispatch(ws_.get_executor(),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &Session::on_run,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_run()
    {
        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
            websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                beast::role_type::server));

        // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::response_type& res)
            {
                res.set(http::field::server,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                    "websocket - server - async");
            }));
        //ws_.read_message_max(64 * 1024 * 1024);
        //ws_.write_buffer_bytes(16 * 1024 * 1024);

        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_accept(
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &Session::on_accept,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec)
            return socket_fail(ec, "accept");

        // Read a message
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_in_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &Session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        // This indicates that the session was closed
        if (ec == websocket::error::closed) {
            return;
        }
        else if (ec == beast::error::timeout)
        {
            std::cout << "Read Request Failed" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (ec) {
            socket_fail(ec, "read");
        }

        buffer_in_.consume(buffer_in_.size());
        buffer_in_.clear();
        if (ws_.is_open())
        {
            ws_.async_read(
                buffer_in_,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                    &Session::on_read,
                    shared_from_this()));
        }
    }

    bool isRunning()
    {
        return ws_.is_open();
    }
};



class WebSocketManager
{

private:
    WebSocketManager()
    {
        __session_update_timer = std::thread(&WebSocketManager::updateSessions, this);
    }

    static WebSocketManager* __instance;

    ~WebSocketManager()
    {

    }

    std::thread __socket_thread;

    void run();

    bool __is_running = false;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Session>> __sessions;
    std::thread __session_update_timer;

    void updateSessions()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
            std::weak_ptr<Session> weak_session;
            for (std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Session>>::iterator itr = __sessions.begin(); itr != __sessions.end();)
            {
                if (itr->get()->isRunning())
                {
                    ++itr;
                }
                else
                {
                    weak_session = *itr;
                    //(*itr).reset();
                    itr = __sessions.erase(itr);
                }
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
        }
    }

protected:
    void registerSession(std::shared_ptr<Session>& pSession)
    {
        __sessions.push_back(pSession);
    }

public:
    WebSocketManager(WebSocketManager const&) = delete;
    void operator=(WebSocketManager const&) = delete;

    static WebSocketManager* Instance()
    {
        if (__instance == nullptr)
        {
            __instance = new WebSocketManager();
        }
        return __instance;
    }

    void startBehavior()
    {
        if (!__is_running)
        {
            __is_running = true;

            __socket_thread = std::thread(std::bind(&WebSocketManager::run, this));
        }
    }

    size_t getActiveSessions() const
    {
        return __sessions.size();
    }

    const std::string SRV_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";
    const int PORT = 617;
    const int MAX_THREAD_COUNT = 5;

    friend class Listener;
};

class Listener
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Listener>
{
private:
    net::io_context& ioc_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

    Listener();

public:
    Listener(net::io_context& ioc, tcp::endpoint endpoint)
        :
        ioc_(ioc)
        , acceptor_(ioc)
    {
        beast::error_code ec;

        // Open the acceptor
        acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            socket_fail(ec, "open");
            return;
        }

        // Allow address reuse
        acceptor_.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            socket_fail(ec, "set_option");
            return;
        }

        // Bind to the server address
        acceptor_.bind(endpoint, ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            socket_fail(ec, "bind");
            return;
        }

        // Start listening for connections
        acceptor_.listen(
            net::socket_base::max_listen_connections, ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            socket_fail(ec, "listen");
            return;
        }
    }

    void run()
    {
        do_accept();
    }

    void do_accept()
    {
        // The new connection gets its own strand
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            net::make_strand(ioc_),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &Listener::on_accept,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
    {
        if (ec)
        {
            socket_fail(ec, "accept");
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Session create" << std::endl;
            // Create the session and run it
            std::shared_ptr<Session> session = std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket));
            WebSocketManager::Instance()->registerSession(session);
            session->run();
        }

        // Accept another connection
        do_accept();
    }
};

WebSocketManager* WebSocketManager::__instance(nullptr);

void WebSocketManager::run()
{
    auto const address = net::ip::make_address(SRV_ADDRESS.c_str());
    auto const threads = std::max(1, 1);

    net::io_context ioc{ threads };

    std::make_shared<Listener>(ioc, net::ip::tcp::endpoint{ address, static_cast<unsigned short>(PORT) })->run();

    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    v.reserve(threads - 1);
    for (auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        v.emplace_back([&ioc] {ioc.run(); });
    }
    ioc.run();
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    WebSocketManager::Instance()->startBehavior();
    _CrtMemState S1;
    uint16_t counter = 600;
    bool session_detected = false;
    int skip = true;

    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&S1);

    while (counter > 0)
    {
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&S1);
        std::cout << S1.lSizes[1] << "," << S1.lSizes[2] << std::endl;
        if (WebSocketManager::Instance()->getActiveSessions() > 0)
        {
            session_detected = true;
        }
        else if (WebSocketManager::Instance()->getActiveSessions() == 0 && session_detected)
        {
            if (skip) skip = false;
            else
            {
                session_detected = false;
                _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
                skip = true;
            }
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


The essence is missing. I'm pretty sure that __sessions is a list or vector of std::shared_ptr<Session> - which is probably keeping the sessions alive. Please make the sample self-contained. Also, double-underscores are reserved everywhere

Without a [mre] it's difficult to tell but I'd guess you've got a shared pointer cycle somewhere, change some to weak pointers to break it

Tried to make it self-contained, but several things were flabber-ghasting. Mostly the router and websocket manager seem to be entangled in a confusing way. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e390a135fb529ae

@sehe I agree the router and socket manager is confusing. I have found double calls that I have since removed that double the amount of work required and confusion. After removing, I think a lot of the friendships can be destroyed.
Reviewing/testing, I have been very skeptical of the destruction of the session variable.

That's not really a question. However perhaps you can find some inspiration from the weak_ptr idioms I employ in many of my Beast/Asio answers. At least the explicit register/deregister is an antipattern. As isRunning - that should probably just be std::weak_ptr::expired

Further investigation, I have found a couple reasons for the memory allocations that I was seeing using _CrtMemCheckpoint. First validation is the destruction of the session is happening correctly. I saved a copy of the point as a weak_ptr and validated the number of use counts went from 1 strong, 3 weak to 0 strong and 1 weak. The 1 weak was the local variable. Next, the closing of the socket. Adding the lines in the destructor to close the lowest layer deallocated a lot of memory.

The last unknown was the 40 bytes that were left was the Listener getting ready to accept a new connection via do_accept(). The making of the net::make_strand seem to be permanent since this will allocate additional 40 bytes for each new async_accept. How do I clear up the previously created listener and return those 40 bytes back to the heap?
